# Error en la visualizacion de fotos en un gridView

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un gridView en el cual quiero visualizar datos de los trabajadores incluyendo la foto del trabajador, pero no me visualiza la foto sino que me sale un icono. Las fotos estan almacenadas en una columna llamada foto de sql server

'Este es el codigo del gridView'

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdTrabajadores" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Foto" HeaderText="Foto" ControlStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-Width="150"
                ControlStyle-Height="150" ItemStyle-Height="150"></asp:ImageField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

'Este es el codigo del pageLoad'

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            lblTrabajador.Text = Session["Nombre"] + " " + Session["Apellido1"];
            cmdPersonal.Connection = conexion;
            conexion.Open();
            daPersonal = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdPersonal);
            cmdPersonal.CommandText = "cdt.pr_Trabajadores";
            cmdPersonal.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            daPersonal.Fill(dtPersonal);
            grdTrabajadores.DataSource = dtPersonal;
            grdTrabajadores.DataBind();
            conexion.Close();
        }
        
    }
```

'Este es el codigo del procedimiento'

```
create procedure cdt.pr_Trabajadores
as
begin
    select Trabajadores.Foto as 'Foto', trabajadores.Nombre as Nombre, trabajadores.Apellido1 
    as Apellido, puestoTrabajo.PuestoTrabajo as Puesto
    from cdt.Trabajadores as trabajadores left join
    cdt.PuestoTrabajo as puestoTrabajo on trabajadores.IdPuesto=puestoTrabajo.IdPuesto
end
```

Comment: ¿Que tipo de fotos usas png jpg bmp ?

Comment: @rexxarcat el tipo de foto es jpeg

Answer (score -1):

Si tienes almacenada la foto en SQL debe estar en un campo Varbinary , por lo tanto tienes que hacer una conversion para poderla usar en el Gridview.

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/27/Display-images-from-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASP.Net-GridView-control/

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.